# Excel 365 functions LEN, LEFT and RIGHT, and FIND not yielding correct results

Tags: date, excel-dates

I am trying to separate a date & time stamp (e.g 01/09/2017  00:08:05) in cell C2 of column C in to two columns as Date (01/09/2017)and time (00:08:05).

1. The cell format of the date & time stamp (C2) is Custom (JJJJ"-"MM"-"TT" "hh":"mm":"ss)
2. In cell K2, the function =LEN(C2) yields 15 instead of 19. Why is it so?
3. In cell L2, the function =FIND(" ", C2,1) yields #value error. Why is it so? I expect it to return 11.
4. In cell M2, the function =LEFT(C2,8) yields 42979.00. The cell format if M2 is Date (2012-03-14)

Comment: Cell format is not the actual cell value. You should convert to a string, and then using such functions.